# Nodejs function scope

Tags: node.js

Can someone help me understand why the following doesn't work?  I'm trying to wrap my head around javascript and nodejs.  I just want the function to return the hash.  I may not be understanding function scope correctly.

```
function generateHash() {

    var hash = '';

    var toHash = function(stdout){
        hash = new Buffer(stdout).toString('base64');
        //console.log(hash);
        return hash;
    };

    exec("date +%Y-%m-%d", function(err, stdout, stderr){
        var todaysDate = stdout.trim();
        toHash(todaysDate);
    });

};

console.log(generateHash());
```

The result I get is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything - hence `undefined`.

In node there's a convention about [asynchronous execution](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node/#callbacks) - functions should accept callback as their last argument and this callback is passed error and result as arguments. You can see it in your example:

```
exec("date +%Y-%m-%d", function(err, stdout, stderr){
        var todaysDate = stdout.trim();
        toHash(todaysDate);
    });
```

`exec` isn't returning anything - instead it accepts aforementioned callback. This callback is called when the action is completed and is given either an error or all the other arguments. If you want to call async function you have to be async too! so you should change your `generateHash` function to be async.

You could also spot that your callback to `exec` doesn't do nor return anything it just calls `toHash` - dead ends are often symptoms of problems with code.

Your async code could look like this:

```
function generateHash(callback) {
    var toHash = function(stdout){
        return new Buffer(stdout).toString('base64');
    };

    exec("date +%Y-%m-%d", function(err, stdout, stderr){
        var todaysDate = stdout.trim();
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, toHash(todaysDate));
    });

};

generateHash(function(err, hash) {
    console.log(hash);
});
```